# "Typing Fingers" is in need of cleanup

Tags: support

I found a question here that needs cleanup when I was reviewing.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90066/app-or-webapp-for-learning-touch-type-on-ios-with-apple-wireless-keyboard

It got protected by Community about 3 minutes before I posted this question. It contains a surprising amount of answers in the shape of "This app is good. I tried it" that the answer thread now looks like a chat room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All five answers that were posted by the one reputation users are spam.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/209032
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/209035
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/209037
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/209038
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/209041

Downvote, flag them as spam and move on. You don't need to ask a meta question for things like this as a quick message in chat will suffice, [as was already done](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24502416#24502416).

Comment: Spam  users destroyed. Thanks for flagging.